# Bring to or bring into

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I'm a non-native English speaker.
I read this sentence on a magazine article on Googie style:
"One of the key things about this style is that it wasn't for wealthy people's houses. Googie brought the spirit of the modern age to the daily life"

Why did the journalist write "brought to" and not "brought into"?
Is that correct?

Comment: Note: Googie-themed architecture was popular among motels, coffee houses and gas stations. The style later became widely known as part of the mid-century modern style.

Comment: Does the sentence really end with "to the daily life"?

Comment: You can bring something to daily life or into daily life; both are correct although the latter is more idiomatic.

Comment: ["And it brought that spirit of the modern age to **their** daily lives."](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/googie-architecture-of-the-space-age-122837470/)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, and there is not much difference. I assume the author used the word "to" because it could imply a sense of introduction. For example:

> the spirit of the modern age was introduced TO their daily life.

It is an initial encounter, whereas "into" gives a feeling of the "spirit" being apart of their life.

Again, they can be used interchangeably, so this is most likely just over-analyzing the sentence in an attempt to answer the question: "Why did the journalist write 'brought to' and not 'brought into'?"

In short: Yes, it is correct, but only the author knows why they chose the verbiage that they did.

Comment: Only when speaking metaphorically, as this does.  Literally, "brought into" has to indicate that something was brought *inside* something else.

Comment: @Mary worth noting, thanks!